# How can I access values outside of Spark GraphX .map loop?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, colt, rdd

Brand new to Apache Spark and I'm a little confused how to make updates to a value that sits outside of a `.mapTriplets` iteration in GraphX. See below:

```
def mapTripletsMethod(edgeWeights: Graph[Int, Double], stationaryDistribution: Graph[Double, Double]) = {
  val tempMatrix: SparseDoubleMatrix2D = graphToSparseMatrix(edgeWeights)

  stationaryDistribution.mapTriplets{ e =>
      val row = e.srcId.toInt
      val column = e.dstId.toInt
      var cellValue = -1 * tempMatrix.get(row, column) + e.dstAttr
      tempMatrix.set(row, column, cellValue) // this doesn't do anything to tempMatrix
      e
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is due to the design of an `RDD` and there's no simple way to update the `tempMatrix` value. When I run the above code the `tempMatrix.set` method does nothing. It was rather difficult to try to follow the problem in the debugger.

Does anyone have an easy solution? Thank you!

## Edit

I've made an update above to show that `stationaryDistribution` is a graph RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make tempMatrix be of type `RDD[((Int,Int), Double)]` -- that is, each entry is a pair where the first element is in turn a `(row,col)` pair. Then use the [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) class to combine that with ((row,col),weight) triplets generated by your `mapTriplets` call. (So, don't think of it as *updating* the tempMatrix, but rather combining two RDDs to get a third.)

If you need to support stationary distribution graphs where there is more than one edge per vertex pair it gets a little tricky: you'll probably need to combine those edges in a reduction pass to create an RDD with one entry per pair, with a list of weights, and then apply all the weights to a given (row,col) pair at the same time. Otherwise it's very simple.

Notice that `PairRDDFunctions' on the one hand give you ways to combine multiple RDDs into one, or on the other hand to pull the values out into a Map on the master. Assuming that the distribution matrix is large enough to merit an RDD in the first place, I think you should do the whole thing on RDDs.

Another approach is to make the tempMatrix be a GraphRDD too, which may or may not make sense depending on what you're going to do with it next.

Comment: thanks for this. i definitely need to take a closer look at how RDDs function. I'm going to attempt this and get back to you, and perhaps update your answer with some sample code. Thanks!